# Razor Page - String with whitespace from C# code is shortened when stored in html data attribute

Tags: c#, html, razor-pages, custom-data-attribute

I am working on Razor Page (.NET Core 6) and trying to store data in html data attribute. The problem is that: if the data is the string from C# code and it has whitespace, the string will be split by whitespace and stored only the first item.

For example, if I store a static string directly in data attribute ("data-comment" in this case), it will work perfectly fine (the log show "abc def" correctly):

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<div>
    @{
        <input id="input_data" type="text" data-comment="abc def" />
        <button onclick="LogComment();">Log</button>
    }
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function LogComment() {
            const comment = $("#input_data").data("comment");

            console.log(`comment: ${comment}`);    //> comment: abc def
        }
    </script>
}
```

---

However, when I get the string data from C# code the string will be shorthened to only "abc":

```
...
<div>
    @{
        string comment = "abc def";

        <input id="input_data" type="text" data-comment=@comment />
        <button onclick="LogComment();">Log</button>
    }
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function LogComment() {
            const comment = $("#input_data").data("comment");

            console.log(`comment: ${comment}`);    //> comment: abc
            // Also, if the string is null, the log will return "comment: /" (with slash)
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add quotes around the attribute value:

```
<input id="input_data" type="text" data-comment="@comment" />
```

When you omit the quotes the generated html result is the following:

```html
<input id="input_data" type="text" data-comment="abc" def>
```

So this is why `$("#input_data").data("comment");` returns `"abc"`. It is always helpful to use your browser's developer tools to inspect the generated html output.

Comment: This, but it could be worth explaining that otherwise it would result in `<input data-comment=abc def />` which in html would add a separate property called `def`